# Marker Animation on polylines in primefaces JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, polyline, primefaces-gmap

I want to show moving marker along polyline in gmap of Primefaces. Does gmap supports marker animation along polyline? I have searched but did not find any useful link.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this [animation on polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate) with [Primefaces GMap Polyline](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/polylines.xhtml).
If yes then you can achieve this by getting Polyline Object in JavaScript and then just pass that object to GMap mentioned example (animation on polyline).

```
function initMap(){
    var gmap = PF('gmap').getMap();                             
    var line = gmap.polylines[0];              
    animateCircle(line);
}
function animateCircle(line) {
      var count = 0;
      window.setInterval(function() {
        count = (count + 1) % 200;

        var icons = line.get('icons');
        icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
        line.set('icons', icons);
    }, 20);
  }
```

Just call javascript funtion from your code. Hopefully this will help someone.